# How to make Toggle from my sidebar menu in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to apply an example of a responsive dashboard that I saw on the internet for my Angular application.

The example dashboard is built only with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, without any framework.

In the example I'm doing, the button to do the Toggle in the menu is only available when the screen is less than 750px. I wanted the Toggle button in the menu to be always available, regardless of the screen size.

I know I can use Angular Material to do this, but as I am still starting my studies in Angular, I want to try this basic example to understand how it works ^^

The Angular code I am developing I put on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-font-awesome-starter-c3jdpl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

And here's the article I'm using as a reference to do this test: https://medium.com/better-programming/build-a-responsive-modern-dashboard-layout-with-css-grid-and-flexbox-bd343776a97e

Can you tell me how I can do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* Non-mobile styles, 750px breakpoint */
@media only screen and (min-width: 46.875em) {
  
}
```

Remove all code applied to this media query. This css overwrites the sidenavigation and components influenced by this sidenav.